# Using Parse's cloud code to automatically push an object from one user to another

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code

I have a feature on my app where one user fills out a form and it saves it to parse. I want to have the object that is saved be sent to user b (there is a pointer to user b in the saved object). I have an afterSave function written for doing this, but am getting errors. Am still new to javascript, so I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendDealToConfirm", function(request, response) {
var sender = request.user;
var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
var task = request.params.task;
var price = request.params.price;
var address = request.params.address;
var time = request.params.time;
var taskP = request.params.taskP;

//send the push
var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);

Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
        alert: "You have a new deal to confirm!",
        task: task,
        poster: sender,
        price: price,
        address: address,
        time: time,
        taskP: taskP
    }
}).then(function(){
    response.success("Deal was sent successfully.")
        }, function(error){
    response.error("Deal failed to send:" + error.message);
      });
});
```

Here is my iOS code

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendDealToConfirm"
                   withParameters: @{@"recipientId": self.doer, @"task": self.details[@"Task_Name"], @"price": self.dealPrice, @"address": self.dealAddress, @"time": self.dealTime, @"taskP": self.details[@"Task_Pointer"]}
                            block:^(NSString *success, NSError *error) {

                                if (!error){
                                    NSLog(@"Push successful");
                                } else {
                                    NSLog(@"Error in push %@", error);
                                }

                            }];
```

**EDIT** Here is the crash report

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'PFObjects are not allowed here.'

Comment: Can you put an exception breakpoint on, run again, and let us know which line of code is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Your cloud code seems fine but is it possible that one of the objects of the following `NSDictionary` might be a `PFObject`?

```
@{@"recipientId": self.doer, @"task": self.details[@"Task_Name"], @"price": self.dealPrice, @"address": self.dealAddress, @"time": self.dealTime, @"taskP": self.details[@"Task_Pointer"]}
```

Because, afaik Parse do not allow `PFObject`s in `Parse.Cloud.define`
Try to pass the `PFObject`s `id` as `NSString` to the parameters and in the cloud code create an object with the id.